Why is my vector 'folding' algorithm not working correctly?
First, here's my code:
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> vector1;
    vector<int> nr_notate_separat;
    int n;
    int nr;

    cin>>n;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin>>nr;
        vector1.push_back(nr);
    }

    while(vector1.size() > 1)
    {
        if(vector1.size() % 2 == 1)
        {
                nr_notate_separat.push_back(vector1[vector1.size() - 1]);
                vector1.pop_back();
        }

        vector<int> vector2;

        for(int i = 0; i < vector1.size() / 2; i++)
            {
                    vector2.push_back(vector1[i] + vector1[vector1.size() - 1 - i]);
            }

        vector1 = vector2;
    }

    nr_notate_separat.push_back(vector1[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i < nr_notate_separat.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<nr_notate_separat[i]<<endl;
    }


    return 0;

}

I'm currently working on a problem with vectors, here's the information:

Requirement:
We have a vector with n natural numbers. We will apply a folding operation several times until we reach a vector consisting of a single element (on an application of the operation the vector changes and the following applications are made on modified vector).  On a folding, the last element overlaps the first, the penultimate over the second, the antepenultimate over the third, etc. If 'n' is odd, the last item cannot fold, so it is extracted and noted separately. The new vector will have n/2 items, and each is equal to the sum of the two that reach each other after folding.  On the newly obtained vector, a new folding operation is applied, and so on until we reach a vector consisting of a single element, which can no longer fold, but is noted separately.  Determine the numbers denoted separately.
Example:
input:
11,
2 3 4 7 5 6 2 1 9 4 6.
output:
6 13 30
Explanation:
The initial vector has an odd number of elements, so the middle one, $6$, will be written separately.
After folding, the new vector is: 8 7 13 8 7
This vector also has an odd number of elements, so $13$ is written separately.
After folding we arrive at the vector 15 15.
It has an even number of elements, so we don't write anything separately, and after folding we get the vector: $30$. This number is written down separately and we stop.

The Problem:
When I run my code, I get the output: '6, 11, 32'
Important: the problem was in Romanian, so I translated it into English, so some parts might not make sense.
I even tried ChatGPT, and he was not able to write the program correctly!

I even tried ChatGPT,,,  Why do you expect ChatGPT a LLM that' doesn't know a thing about C++ will give you anything close to a correct C++ program?

"I even tried ChatGPT, and he was not able to write the program correctly!" - C++ and ChatGPT is not a good combo. Just don't.

Not sure why this is downvoted so much. Yes, both using the wrong element and using ChatGPT are beginner mistakes,  but that is not a reason for a downvote.

@MSalters "Not sure why this is downvoted so much." -- One reason is that it lacks content. There is code, the toy problem the code was created for and the actual output of the program. There is no evidence of debugging (so "does not show any research effort"). Furthermore, there is no effort to narrow down the issue, meaning that this question is likely only useful to someone else who is working on the same toy problem and who came up with the exact same code (so "not useful" for the most part). Those are legitimate reasons for downvoting.

When your while loop detects vector1 has an odd size, you are noting and popping the element at the end of vector1.  However, this is the wrong element! You need to note and pop the element in the middle of vector1 instead, eg:
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 5 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 9 | 4 | 6 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                      ^                   ^
                pop this one!        not this one!

//nr_notate_separat.push_back(vector1[vector1.size() - 1]);
//vector1.pop_back();

size_t middle = vector1.size() / 2;
nr_notate_separat.push_back(vector1[middle]);
vector1.erase(vector1.begin()+middle);

The instructions could have been more clear about this:

If 'n' is odd, the last item cannot fold, so it is extracted and noted separately.

Here, last is not referring to the final element at the end of the vector, but to the remaining element which can't be folded, which is the middle element.  The provided explanation proves this is true.

For starters this header
#include<fstream>

is not used. So you may remove it.
There is no need to define an additional vector to output the result. You could output the result sequantially while processing the source vector.
This part of the code
if(vector1.size() % 2 == 1)
{
        nr_notate_separat.push_back(vector1[vector1.size() - 1]);
        vector1.pop_back();
}

is logically wrong. You need to output (or store in the vector nr_notate_separat ) the middle element of the source vector vector1 instead of the last element.
Thus the next for loop
for(int i = 0; i < vector1.size() / 2; i++)
    {
            vector2.push_back(vector1[i] + vector1[vector1.size() - 1 - i]);
    }

incorrectly builds the intermediate vector vector2 because the last element of the source vector vector1  was already removed from it in the preceding for loop.
Pay attention to that instead of the for loop you could use for example standard algorithm std::transform declared in the header <algorithm>.
Here is a demonstration program written according to the C++14 Standard that shows a correct implementation of the logic of the task.
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6, 2, 1, 9, 4, 6 };
    
    while ( v.size() != 1 )
    {
        std::vector<int> tmp;
        
        auto n = v.size();

        if ( n % 2 ) std::cout << v[n / 2] << '\n';

        std::transform( std::begin( v ), std::next( std::begin( v ), n / 2 ), std::rbegin( v ),
            std::back_inserter( tmp ), std::plus<int>() );
        
        v = tmp;        
    }
    
    std::cout << v.front() << '\n';
}

The program output is
6
13
30

Actually even the temporary vector tmp is redundant. You could process the source vector like
auto last = std::transform( std::begin( v ), std::next( std::begin( v ), n / 2 ), std::rbegin( v ),
    std::begin( v ), std::plus<int>() );

v.erase( last, std::end( v ) ); 

